# Can we use a List to mimic a temp table in ef core for executing a MERGE statement?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I am doing the below in a .net console app.

I am performing a MERGE statement between two tables , as follows:**(as a raw sql in .net Core)**

```
            var SqlMergeStatement = @"MERGE TAR AS TARGET
                                USING SRC AS SOURCE 
                                ON (TARGET.Id= SOURCE.Id) 
                                WHEN MATCHED AND 
                               -----
                               -----                
                                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
                                THEN INSERT (
                                   ----
                                   ----)
                                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
                                THEN DELETE    
                                OUTPUT 
                                    CASE WHEN $action = 'INSERT' THEN Inserted.Id
                                            ELSE Deleted.Id
                                       END ,
                                   ----
                                   ----
                                    $action
                                    INTO table3 (Id,----,[Action]);
                                Go;
```

**What I am trying to achieve is:**

1. Using a List which is populated at run time in the Merge:

   `List<Entity> data = new List<Entity>() ;  // populated during run-time.`
2. I am trying to use **data** as the source table in the MERGE statement.

**Why I am trying to do this:**

2. The Source table to which I need to perform a merge is populated through an API response.
3. Inserting the data to a temp table and then using that for the merge wastes resources and is time consuming.

I don't know if the above is possible, Open to alternate ways to achieve the above.

Comment: In SQL 2016+ you can serialize the data into a JSON doc and send it to SQL Server using an NVarchar(max) parameter, and then use OPENJSON. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: why not ask the `API response` persist the `temp table` as a real table, the api returns a boolen, instead of those data? then you can run your `merge` as a `stored procedure` for tables?  Round trips always cost more than usual. and you actually don't need return merged view, but it's enough to return a boolen..

Comment: The API response which I am getting is basically the table itself and not a boolean. Apologies, But I did not get the part of making the API Response persist temp table as a real table! @Dongdong